# LINQ query using lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I have this linq query, which is working fine, but I want to make it shorter by using a lambda expression. Any suggestions or examples might help.

```
selectedPersons = (from d in entities.PERSONS_DATA
                   where d.PERSON_ID == pid
                   select d).First();
```

Comment: I disagree.  I believe the below is more readable. This is more of a preference than fact.

Comment: That query already is using a lambda expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectedPersons = entities.PERSONS_DATA.First (d => d.PERSON_ID == pid);
```

Comment: why single? why not first?

Comment: You are correct, it should be first.  Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much...didn't thought it would be this simple :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use:

```
electedPersons = entities.PERSONS_DATA.Find(pid);
```

If there is a chance the pid might not match a row the First will throw an exception. So in this case use:

```
electedPersons = entities.PERSONS_DATA.FirstOrDefault(d => d.PERSON_ID == pid);

if(electedPersons != null)
   ....
```